# Swift UI transition does not work as expected

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I'm trying to make a Swift UI transition where a button can be clicked and view 1 will slide downwards out of the bottom of the screen as view 2 slides downwards from the top into the screen. And if view 2 is displayed then view 2 will slide upwards out of the top of the screen as view 1 slides upwards from the bottom of the screen.

I tried to do so with the custom transitions but these do not work. Wrapping the bool change in an Animation also doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
import SwiftUI

extension AnyTransition {
    static var moveOne: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition
            .asymmetric(
                insertion: .move(edge: .bottom),
                removal: .move(edge: .top)
            )
    }
    static var moveTwo: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition
            .asymmetric(
                insertion: .move(edge: .top),
                removal: .move(edge: .bottom)
            )
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var show = true
    var body: some View {
        if !show {
            Rectangle().fill(.red.gradient).frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true) * 0.8, height: widthOrHeight(width: false)).transition(.moveOne)
                .onTapGesture {
                    show.toggle()
                }
        } else {
            Rectangle().fill(.blue.gradient).frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true) * 0.8, height: widthOrHeight(width: false)).transition(.moveTwo)
                .onTapGesture {
                    show.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what an *asymmetric* transition is.

The transition for the blue view is:

- moves downwards when disappearing
- moves upwards when appearing

The transition for the red view is:

- moves upwards when disappearing
- moves downwards when appearing

These are completely *symmetric* - the animation for the view appearing is the exact reverse of the animation for the view disappearing!

So all you need to do is to pass what the view should do when *appearing*, and the symmetry automatically figures out what it should do when disappearing. The red view moves downwards, and the blue view moves upwards.

Wrapping with `withAnimation`, you get:

```
if !show {
    Rectangle().fill(.red)
        .frame(...)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                show.toggle()
            }
        }
} else {
    Rectangle().fill(.blue)
    .frame(...)
    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                show.toggle()
            }
        }
}
```

Side note, I wouldn't recommend calculating the frame like this. Try to find a more SwiftUI way to do whatever layout you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks your explanation was helpful. When I run the code you provided and press on the rectangle there doesn't appear to be any transition, only the color of the rectangle changing. If I do however click on the rectangle twice quickly I can see the correct desired transition. Any thoughts on why it doesn't happen when I click normally, Ive slowed the animation down so you can see.

Comment: @ahmed "only the color of the rectangle changing" You mean it changes instantly? I cannot reproduce that in a new project. Try creating a new project and paste only your "Updated Code" in.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it seems like running it on the previews doesn't work. When I try it on an actual device it does. Thanks a lot works great!